# How to do RSASHA256 in Azure Data Factory

Tags: adobe, azure-data-factory

I want to generate a JWT for Authentication to the Adobe API.
https://developer.adobe.com/developer-console/docs/guides/authentication/JWT/
How would I generate the JWT in Azure Data Factory?

I'm currently stuck with not knowing how to do the RSASHA in Data Factory. Is that possible? If so how?

My Payload is:

```
{
  "exp": 1550001438,
  "iss": "fdsfgsdf@AdobeOrg",
  "sub": "redacted@techacct.adobe.com",
  "https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/s/ent_dataservices_sdk": true,
  "aud": "https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/c/redacted"
}
```

My Header is:

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to write the logic in Azure Batch and use Custom activity in Azure Data Factory to accomplish the task.